# Ember-paper: Cannot set property element of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: ember.js, ember-paper

I am using Ember-paper 0.2 which seems to be latest stable version.
i'm creating navbar learning from [tutorial](https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/144-material-design-with-ember-paper-creating-a-navbar). whenever I add paper-button i am getting error " Cannot set property element of [object Object] which has only a getter".

It looks like i have mistaken some where but not able to figure out what.
Below is my code for navbar.

```
{{#paper-toolbar}}
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      {{logo}}
      <div class="paper-right">
        {{#paper-button size="2"}} {{paper-icon "refresh"}} {{/paper-button}}        
      </div>
  </div>
{{/paper-toolbar}}
{{outlet}}
```

{{logo}} is my logo component below is the component code

```
<img src="assets/images/logo_sm_app.png" class="logo">
```

I have defined my styles in app.scss file

I have used steps as stated in the ember-paper documentation. Could you please tell me what is missing?
Below is the stack trace of the error i am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property element of [object Object] which has only a getter
    at Class.didInsertElement (ripple-mixin.js:31)
    at Class.superWrapper [as didInsertElement] (ember.debug.js:40424)
    at Class.trigger (ember.debug.js:42259)
    at Class.superWrapper [as trigger] (ember.debug.js:40424)
    at CurlyComponentManager.didCreate (ember.debug.js:12725)
    at Environment.commit (ember.debug.js:50904)
    at Environment.commit (ember.debug.js:9283)
    at InteractiveRenderer._renderRoots (ember.debug.js:12121)
    at InteractiveRenderer._renderRootsTransaction (ember.debug.js:12150)
    at InteractiveRenderer._renderRoot (ember.debug.js:12071)
```

Comment: Is component name is `logo`, i think name should contain`-`. and also what will happen when you remove `{{log}}` ?

Comment: Its {{company-logo}} instead of {{logo}}. There's no change even when i remove {{logo}}.

Comment: You should really use latest versions, they are much more stable. 0.2 is very outdated. Also, we are really close to 1.0!

Comment: @miguelcobain: Upgrading to 1.0 worked. I am able to use material now. Thanks for the response